# Yacto/BitBake new dir does not show up

Tags: embedded-linux, bit, yocto, bitbake

I have problem where my newly added directory does not exists when patch we relies on it is present.

I added new directory (with files) to the existing directory tree (under fs). I have done this by adding the "install" to the do_configure_append. When I run this, it seems to work fine as the new dir/files show up in the source tree as expected.

However, if I add a patch to the SRC_URI which adds dependence on the new source code, the make fails. It almost appears that the patched files run before the new dir is created.

What I am missing/misunderstanding ?

No code

Comment: Code modifications should happen via SRC_URI (e.g. using a patch file that adds the sources you want to add). In any case, you should add the actual recipe here: otherwise it's impossible to say what's going wrong.

Comment: do_patch is run before do_configure

Answer (score 0):

The tasks that matter here, listed in the order they are executed: do_fetch => do_unpack => do_patch => do_configure => do_compile => do_install.

Your patch is applied before the targets files are created. One possible fix:

- Add the ";apply=no" parameter to the patch in SRC_URI, to prevent it from being applied automatically.
- Then, manually apply the patch after the "install" in do_configure.

See https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-tasks-patch for some more info.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the suggestion. What I discovered is that one of the files in the patch is causing me the problem. It is Kconfig which sources Kconfig in my new dir.... for the kernel configurator ? It seems as Kconfig part of patch is applied before files are installed so the make fails.

Not a yocto expert obviously so will look at the link above .. thanks ...